# Res file entry used for Kendo Grid Name causing conditional compilation errors in JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

My grid is defined as follows:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataModels.Picking.PickingAssignmentItemViewModel>()
        .Name(@UserInterface.Resources.GridRes.GridChild)
        ....
        ....
```

When I try run in IE I get a conditional compilation error pointing at the name part in Jquery..(version number) on this line

```
$.ui.plugin.add("resizable", @UserInterface.Resources.GridRes.Grid, {
```

Can anyone suggest a way of stopping the error happening? It's incredibly annoying while debugging.

I've read that I need to add @cc_on for these types of errors but the error I get appears in the dynamic version of this JQuery file so I'm unsure where to put it, and it doesn't like it in the actual view.

I'm using MVC Razor and JQuery

Comment: whts your  IE version ?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned in OP -- 10.0.9200.16466

Comment: we also use  .Name(@UserInterface.Resources.GridRes.GridChild)  syntax but this may be buy in IE

Comment: Can you rephrase the last part please? I don't quite understand.
"but this may be buy in IE – "